# Did GNU ARM Eclipse plugin is deprecated?

Tags: plugins, arm, eclipse-cdt, gnu, stm32f4

I tried to install GNU ARM Eclipse plugin on windows. But the sourceforge updatesite links are not in use, all are saying deprecated. Does eclipse supporting GNU ARM plugin currently or not? Previous forums and lots of youtube videos showing installing the GNU ARM plugin with the old link, but now it is saying those are migrated to bintray something, but whatever no updatesite links to be found for installing the plugin.
I want to test my STM32F446RE nucleo board on eclipse ide. but I cant found the proper plugin to install. any help is much appreciated.

I tried these links,

GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-ins
http://gnuarmeclipse.sourceforge.net/updates

CDT - https://download.eclipse.org/embed-cdt/updates/v6/

But didn't work.

Comment: If the plugin is not available anymore, you should probably give a try to [Eclipse IDE for Embedded C/C++ Developers](https://eclipse-embed-cdt.github.io/). It can be downloaded from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/), and is an official Eclipse Foundation project. There will likely be a fair amount of documentation/tutorials available.

Comment: thanks your suggestion will work. But actually I want to use the real eclipse instead of "Eclipse IDE for Embedded C/C++ Developers", because I'm working on a software which is look like an eclipse based IDE. so I want to do cross compile and make this to work by installing the ARM toolchain and plugin. actually I tried one another way which is, I generated "Makefile" project from stm32cubeMX and import that on eclipse IDE, but for that also ARM toolchain is required to do cross compile and config the project to build successfully. Is there any other way to do? please help if it is there.